How to develop Mui Multiple selector
i want to develop like this dropDown how to develop using material ui - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/ enter image description here
i want to develop like this drop down , how to develop it , i want to sample code this is my array
const menuData = [
        {
            mainItem: "FRESHWATER FISH",
            mainId: "main001",
            subMenu: [
                {
                    subId: "sub001",
                    subItem: "Discus",
                },
                {
                    subId: "sub002",
                    subItem: "Gold Fish",
                    cateItem: [
                        {
                            cateId: "cate001",
                            cateItem: "Oranda Goldfish",
                        },
                        {
                            cateId: "cate002",
                            cateItem: "Black Oranda Goldfish",
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            mainItem: "MARINE FISH",
            mainId: "main002",
        },
        {
            mainItem: "FRESHWATER PLANTS",
            mainId: "main003",
        },
    ];


Material UI does not provide a component with that capability.
You could try something like this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-cascader-nzc656?file=/src/demo.js
But tbh, it isn't a very developer-friendly solution as it is.
In your place, I would check a 3rd party library like this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-cascader?activeTab=readme
